# Dynamic Dropdown in HTML error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i work in project that has Dynamic Dropdown that change second one data depend on the first one but i have problem in it .
the project content from 3 files (index.html,getcountry.php.script.js)

index.html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<select id="slctmake"></select></br>
<select id="slctmodel"></select>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

getcountry.php code

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$query="SELECT DISTINCT  country FROM `widgets` where country !='' ";
$data=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$makes = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    array_push($makes,$row["country"]);
    }
        echo json_encode($makes);

?>
```

script.js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("getcountry.php", success =function(data)
    {
        var options = "";
        for (i=0 ; i < data.length ; i++ ){
            options +="<option value '".data[i].tolowercase()+"'>"+data[i]+"'</option>";
            }
            $("#slctmake").append(options);
    });
});
```

so please guys could anyone help me in my problem as there's no data selected and iam sure that the select code right as i test it well

Answer (score 0):

Look at your js code:

`options +="<option value '".data[i].tolowercase()+"'>"+data[i]+"'</option>"`;

You have syntax errors, it should be:

```
options +="<option value='"+data[i].tolowercase()+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>
```

Comment: i fixed this error and still have no data , could you help me more , please

Comment: check if the ajax is getting the data

Comment: sorry because iam still beginner , could you please till me how to check this

Comment: Before the for loop write console.log(data) and then check in your browser dev tool (F12), then go to console and you should ser your data